# How to import date strings into javascript as UTC objects using HighStock charting?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm in the process of creating a graph using HighStock (from HighCharts). I need to somehow convert the xAxis data to UTC objects but for some reason it is not graphing out the correct dates (it uses the default Jan1st).

If I import a list like ["2013-08-05 10:38:30","2013-08-06 10:38:30"] into javascript, how could I convert each element to a UTC object?

Many thanks!

$(function() {$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

```
        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },
        xAxis : {
            data : ["2013-08-05 10:38:30","2013-08-06 10:38:30"],
            type : 'datetime'
        },
        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },
        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : [10,20],
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice to get your all string, then use i.e [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function, and use Date.UTC() function. After it you can use this as x parameter in point in serie. Like:

```
series:[{
data:[[Date.UTC(2012,2,2),10],[Date.UTC(2013,2,2),3]]
}]
```

Data cannot be used in xAxis.